# How to prevent duplicate insert with insert return in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to create some rules for my DB to prevent duplicate inserts, but since we're also hibernate, the .save() is called insert xxx RETURNING *

I can't seem to make the insert rule play well with the insert returning.

```
CREATE TABLE test ( aaa int, bbb int);

insert into test VALUES(1, 2);

CREATE RULE "testRule1" AS ON INSERT TO  test
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test 
                WHERE (aaa, bbb)=(NEW.aaa, NEW.bbb))
  DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

If I try to insert with just 1 conditional rule

```
insert into test VALUES(1, 2);
ERROR:  cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation "test"
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.

CREATE RULE "testRule2" AS ON INSERT TO  test
  DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO test VALUES(new.*)
  RETURNING test.*;
```

If I try to insert with both conditional and unconditional rules

```
insert into test VALUES(1, 2);
ERROR:  infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "test"
```

Is this impossible to achieve with my setup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to avoid inserting duplicates is to define the fields as `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`)

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
aaa integer,
bbb integer,
val text, /* The reason why I added this field is explained later */
UNIQUE (aaa,bbb)
)
```

Inserting will fail with an error code if a tuple already exists (receiving error codes from a database is a good thing, as I explained recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149272/equivalent-of-on-conflict-do-nothing-for-update-postgres/54151151#54151151)).

If it is unacceptable for you to have errors or if you want to insert multiple records in a single `insert` without having to care which one violates the `UNIQUE` constraint, the correct syntax is to use the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

```
INSERT INTO Test values (1,1,'Some value')
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

Basically the first record with a unique tuple will be inserted. That is compatible even if the query itself tries to insert duplicates such as the case below:

```
INSERT INTO Test values (2,2,'Will be inserted'), (2,2,'Will not be inserted')
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

Of course, this will also allow you to have the `RETURNING` clause in the same query.

Comment: right, but I want to know if I can use JPA default CRUD methods without overriding each insert methods to add the extra ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, is this possible? Or do I need to use raw queries for all my inserts?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is possible. Have a look to my edit but note I do not recommend implementing that. You **will** reach some limitations some day and pay a high cost to switch back.

Comment: Thanks, I gave up on making the RULES work and just override all insert statements with an ON CONFLICT clause.